# Using \pgfmathparse and \ifnum for a TikZ checkerboard

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I am trying to produce a 6-by-6 checkboard of small circles, alternating colour between red and black.

To do this I have attempted to use `\pgfmathparse` and `\ifnum` in order to decide if to colour a circle red or back:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,5} \foreach \y in {0,...,5}
{
  \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2)}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0{\path[fill=black] (\x*0.5cm,\y*0.5cm) circle (0.1cm);}
  \else{\path[fill=red] (\x*0.5cm,\y*0.5cm) circle (0.1cm);}\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Although the code errors when I attempted to run it through `pdflatex` with `! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.` and `! Missing number, treated as zero.` it does produce the expected result.

What precisely am I doing wrong with regards to the calculation and how should one go about producing such a picture?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you just need to add `int` before the modulo operator (otherwise it returns a float that `\ifnum`doesn't like), thus:

```
\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x+\y,2))}
```

and all is good :)

Answer (score 13):

Since you are already using the `pgfmath` library, you may as well use the conditional syntax from that:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,5} \foreach \y in {0,...,5}
{
  \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "black" : "red"}
  \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
  \path[fill=\colour] (\x*0.5cm,\y*0.5cm) circle (0.1cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

with no errors.  (I'm using TikZ/PGF 2.10; I'm not sure when this conditional syntax was implemented.)

Answer (score 2):

`\ifnum` compares two integers so you must ensure that the numbers are really integers. So a working code, combining the previous answers could be:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,5} 
  \foreach \y in {0,...,5}
  {
    \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x+\y,2))}
    \let\r\pgfmathresult
    \ifnum\r=0
      \path[fill=red] (\x*0.5cm,\y*0.5cm) circle (0.1cm);
    \else
      \path[fill=black] (\x*0.5cm,\y*0.5cm) circle (0.1cm);
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Observe that instead of using `\pgfmathresult` directly, its value it is dumped in the `\r` macro.

Comment: Is there an advantage to \let\foo\pgfmathresult so far as good practise goes?

Comment: @Freddie: I've noticed that `\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{int(...)}` doesn't return an integer (you get the `.0` on the end), which you need the `\let\r\pgfmathresult` for.  Also, you never know when a TikZ command will overwrite `\pgfmathresult`, so saving it is a good idea if you need to refer to it later.  However, in a case like this, I don't think there's any need for the `\let\r\pgfmathresult`.  It doesn't hurt, though.

Comment: @Freddie, @Antal: in the code that I posted, the `\edef` is necessary.  If you put `color=\pgfmathresult` then TeX complains (try it).  So Antal is correct (on both counts).

Comment: having to do this is sickeningly disappointing. :-(