# Drawing stars/similar with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, diagrams, asymptote

I'm writing a review for a book at the moment, and I thought I'd be clever and show off what LaTeX is capable of by adding a x-out-of-y stars graphic. Tikz can do many things so I would have thought that a trick like this would be fairly trivial, however it seems that I cannot figure out a macro to draw the shapes at the right size, let alone fancy tricks such as half-filled stars or something similar. I think the code I have so far might be headed in the right direction:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows}

\newcommand*\starfill{%
  \tikz[baseline=(key.base),scale=-3]
  \node[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25, fill=black, draw](key) {S};  
}
```

I've tried to start by drawing a single star shape, but ideally I'd like to define like `\starsranking{number}{total}` that will output the appropriate shaded `number` of stars out of `total`. Is this doable? It doesn't sound particularly difficult.

Comment: The `star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25` are your own options, aren't there? You should have a look at `\foreach`. You need two: one from 1 to `\starpoints` to make the filled stars and one for `\starpoints+1` to 5. The half-filled stars should be do-able with an clipped fill-path.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here's the code for fully filled stars, now slightly improved thanks to Andrew Stacey's [answer to the checkerboard question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/using-pgfmathparse-and-ifnum-for-a-tikz-checkerboard/6711#6711):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand\score[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfxa{#1 + 1}%
  \tikzstyle{scorestars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25, draw, inner sep=1.3pt, anchor=outer point 3]%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., #2} {
      \pgfmathparse{\i<=#1 ? "yellow" : "gray"}
      \edef\starcolor{\pgfmathresult}
      \draw (\i*1.75ex, 0) node[name=star\i, scorestars, fill=\starcolor]  {};
   }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\score{0}{5} A meagre result.

\score{4}{5} Much better

\score{5}{5} Perfect score!

\end{document}
```

[image: ranking stars with tikz]

---

And here's the much more elaborate, much more pointless, floating point scoring star macro (I'll leave the simple one in as well, it's a lot more usable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}

\newcommand\score[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfxa{#1 + 1}%
  \tikzstyle{scorestars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25, draw, inner sep=0.15em, anchor=outer point 3]%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., #2} {
      \pgfmathparse{\i<=#1 ? "yellow" : "gray"}
      \edef\starcolor{\pgfmathresult}
      \draw (\i*1em, 0) node[name=star\i, scorestars, fill=\starcolor]  {};
    }
    \pgfmathparse{#1>int(#1) ? int(#1+1) : 0}
    \let\partstar=\pgfmathresult
    \ifnum\partstar>0
      \pgfmathsetmacro\starpart{#1-(int(#1)}
      \path [clip] ($(star\partstar.outer point 3)!(star\partstar.outer point 2)!(star\partstar.outer point 4)$) rectangle 
      ($(star\partstar.outer point 2 |- star\partstar.outer point 1)!\starpart!(star\partstar.outer point 1 -| star\partstar.outer point 5)$);
      \fill (\partstar*1em, 0) node[scorestars, fill=yellow]  {};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\score{0}{5} That's appalling!

\small\score{2}{5} A meagre result.

\Huge{\score{4.4}{5} Wooo!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like I said, very good (even better since I first said it).  I didn't realize coordinates could be averaged with the `!` like colors can.  I had been going for a style approach so that you could type \node[scorestars,portion=0.25] and get 25% of the star filled.  Looks like you could use the `append after command` key for that.

Comment: Blast, I've already voted for this before your edit.  I think that the floating point version is fantastic.

Comment: That is brilliant. Wow.

Comment: One question though: is it possible to make the stars scale to the text height? So if the text is `\large` the stars will also be correspondingly bigger?

Comment: @zoqaeski: Done! Just use relative lengths ("ex" and "em") for the size and spacing.

Comment: Well thanks for that. I made a few slight changes, I might go digging around in the various options to see if I can turn this into a little package I can use for my reviews on things.

Comment: Great stuff! Always amazed what's (easily) possible with TikZ

Answer (score 16):

[image]

`Asymptote` version `stars.asy`:

```
size(200);
real sc=20;

picture score(real scoreMark=0,guide star=scale(sc)*unitcircle, int maxscore=5, 
  pen linePen=nullpen, pen bgPen=darkblue, pen scorePen=orange){
  picture pic;
  guide[] g;  
  for(int i=0;i<maxscore;++i){
    g.push(shift((2sc*i,0))*star);
  }
  assert(maxscore>0 && scoreMark>=0 && scoreMark<=maxscore,"***** Wrong score.");
  fill(pic,box((-sc,-sc),(maxscore*2sc-sc,sc)),bgPen);
  fill(pic,box((-sc,-sc),(scoreMark*2sc-sc,sc)),scorePen);
  clip(pic,g);
  draw(pic,g,linePen);
  return pic;
}

guide star;
pair p;
for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
  p=rotate(72*i)*N;
  star=star--p;
  star=star--(scale(0.382)*rotate(72*i+36)*N);
}
star=scale(sc)*(star--cycle);

add(score(scoreMark=1,star,maxscore=7),(0,0));
add(score(scoreMark=2,star,maxscore=7,linePen=lightred,bgPen=lightblue),(0,-3sc));
add(score(scoreMark=3.5,star,maxscore=5,linePen=lightred,bgPen=lightblue),(0,-6sc));
add(score(scoreMark=3.75,star,maxscore=4,linePen=olive,bgPen=white,scorePen=lightgreen),(0,-9sc));

add(score(4.2,bgPen=green+opacity(0.3),scorePen=red+opacity(0.5)),(0,3sc));
```

To get a standalone `stars.pdf` run `asy -f pdf stars.asy`.

Answer (score 14):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\makeatletter
\def\LoadPSVars{\pstVerb{/ptcm {\pst@number\psunit div} bind def}}
\makeatother

\def\points{}
\def\Star{%
    \xdef\points{}% cleaning
    \multido{\iR=0+72,\ir=36+72}{5}{\xdef\points{\points (10pt;\iR)(5pt;\ir)}}
    \expandafter\pspolygon\points}

\def\Rating#1{% #1: percentage
    \psscalebox{0.35}{%
    \begin{pspicture}(11pt,-11pt)(111pt,11pt)
    \LoadPSVars
    \psclip{\pscustom{\psLoop{5}{\translate(20pt,0)\Star}}}
        \psframe*[linecolor=yellow](11pt,-11pt)(!#1 11 add ptcm 11 ptcm)
    \endpsclip
    \pscustom{\psLoop{5}{\translate(20pt,0)\Star}}
    \end{pspicture}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \Rating{100} PSTricks
    \item \Rating{50} Asymptote
    \item \Rating{20} Metapost
    \item \Rating{5} TikZ
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### Warning:

- `\rput` will not work inside `\pscustom`. Use `\translate` instead!
- `standalone` discards my `ptcm` operator defined in the preamble, so I have to load it manually inside `pspicture`. It is sad!

Comment: TikZ, I am sorry. It is just an example!

Comment: @armpit: do you still keep that opinion (100 PSTricks, 50 Asymptote, 20 Metapost, 5 TikZ)? ^^

Answer (score 11):

I have written a package for ConTeXt that draws X out of Y graphics. It is primarily meant to draw numbers in presentations. It offers stars as one of the options:

[image]

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]

\definepalet
  [star-colors]
  [active=yellow,
     past=yellow,
   future=gray]

\definevisualcounter
  [stars]
  [markers]
  [mpsetups=visualcounter::markers:star, 
   width=1.5EmWidth,
   distance=0.25EmWidth,
   palette=star-colors, 
  ]

\starttext

\startTEXpage[offset=2mm]
\startitemize
  \item \usevisualcounter[n=1, last=5]{stars} That's appalling!
  \item \usevisualcounter[n=2, last=5]{stars} A meagre result.
  \item \usevisualcounter[n=4, last=5]{stars} Woo!
\stopitemize
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

See [documentation](http://modules.contextgarden.net/dl/t-visualcounter/doc/context/third/visualcounter/visualcounter.pdf) for more details.

As the primary purpose of this module is to display page numbers, it does not support fractional values.

Comment: Hi Aditya, I'm interested in learning a little about MetaPost, and this looks like a nice application of that. However, I wish that your module did support fractional values. How hard would it be to add?

Comment: @faheem: it is relatively easy to add support from fractional values. The module provides a few different counters and fractional values don't make sense for some of them, but for makers it is relatively easy to get. I'll upload an updated version of the module and then reply here

Comment: Thank you very much, Aditya. I look forward to experimenting with MetaPost. Or is it MetaFun now?

Answer (score 6):

Jake's answer is very good.  Here's the extra half star:

```
\node[scorestars,fill=gray] {};
\path node[scorestars,fill=yellow] (s) {} [clip] (s.south west) rectangle (s.north);
```

Comment: ... and here's half a vote.  Oh, wait, they don't come in half steps yet so you'll have to have a whole one.  (Incidentally, why isn't your name in the list of moderator candidates?)

Comment: @Matthew: Can you please tell a TikZ noob how to include this into Jake's code?

Comment: @Andrew: LOL.  I only gave half an answer hoping that Jake could run with it and improve his answer.  I already spent an hour trying to make a customizable portion of the star filled so I think I should quit for now.

Comment: @Andrew: as for the moderator elections, I guess I was just waiting to be asked.

Comment: @Matthew: Consider yourself asked.

Comment: @Matthew: Hehe, I know exactly how you feel about the time spent with this problem. At least the stars are pretty to look at while working on it `=)`

Comment: @Jake: True that. look at the bright side.  You've got 70 rep so far out of it.  That and $2.25 will buy you a cup of coffee at Starbucks.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for asking; I sincerely take it as a compliment.