# How to draw star in TikZ background

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I draw shapes on background via `pgfonlayer`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \draw[rounded corners,fill=red] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
   \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (.8cm);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know the values (coordinates) needed to draw `rectangle` or `circle`, but I have no idea what are the parameters needed to draw a `star`.

We define the starting coordinate; for `rectangle` we give the second coordinate two draw `rectangle` between two points, for `circle`, we give the radius to draw circle around the starting point. What we need to give to draw star around the starting point?

```
\draw[fill=green] (0,0) star ????;
```

**PS.** Sorry, I know this is a basic typical question, but I had a long struggle with it.

Comment: You can just use a `node [star]` for this, which is included in the `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}`. See [Drawing Stars/Similar with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/drawing-stars-similar-with-tikz). The [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) describes the many different node shapes in great detail.

Comment: @Jake It's not difficult to draw shapes with node. I am using this `pgfonlayer` for other packages like `background`, and I prefer to follow the standard procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard procedure"? And what does this have to do with `pgfonlayer`? You can use `node`s in `pgfonlayer` environments.

Comment: @Jake now I get your purpose; I thought you mean using `node` outside `pgfonlayer`.

Comment: An important point is that there is no `star` creator as there is for `circle` or `rectangle`.  In such cases, node shapes are a common way to easily create a wide variety of shapes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you have a macro for drawing stars as well as "n-grams". meaning stars that result when you connect the  diagonals of a regular polygon:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\newcommand{\tstar}[5]{% inner radius, outer radius, tips, rot angle, options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\starangle}{360/#3}
\draw[#5] (#4:#1)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#3}
{ -- (#4+\x*\starangle-\starangle/2:#2) -- (#4+\x*\starangle:#1)
}
-- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\ngram}[4]{% outer radius, tips, rot angle, options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\starangle}{360/#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\innerradius}{#1*sin(90-\starangle)/sin(90+\starangle/2)}
\tstar{\innerradius}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tstar{2}{4}{7}{10}{thick,fill=blue}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tstar{0.5}{3}{20}{0}{thick,fill=green}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \ngram{4}{5}{45}{thick,fill=red}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \ngram{4}{7}{0}{thick,fill=yellow}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very useful codes for customizing the shape of stars!

Comment: In my first try, I used something like Tom's code : `\path \foreach \i  in  {0,2,...,8}{(36*\i:#1) coordinate (a\i)}; etc.` but I abandoned this idea because it seemed to me that it was faster to define directly the shape with ten points, but perhaps I'm wrong...The advantage with Tom'method is to define others shapes with more points.

Answer (score 9):

It's not very difficult to draw a star without a node

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}    

\newcommand\Star[3][]{%
\path[#1] (0  :#3) -- ( 36:#2) 
       -- (72 :#3) -- (108:#2)
       -- (144:#3) -- (180:#2)
       -- (216:#3) -- (252:#2)
       -- (288:#3) -- (324:#2)--cycle;}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Star[fill=gray!30,draw]{2}{4} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's not difficult but what is the advantage of using `\path` over `\node`?

Comment: @Ali A node is something specific. It's a shape around something, genrally a text,it is a structure with anchors and generally, it's not possible to scale it, because you scale the text with it. A path is useful if you need to scale the picture. If you want a specific shape, you need  to draw this shape with `\path` because you can used only  predefined shapes.

Answer (score 7):

This answer summarized useful comments by [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) and [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake), and all credit goes to them

`TikZ` does have creators for common shapes like `circle` and `rectangle`, but not for uncommon shapes like `star`. Thus, for creating `star`, you need to use `\node` instead of `\draw`. The code will look like this

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[star,fill=red,minimum width=1cm] at (0,0) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

I hope this will help someone struggling with shapes in `pgfonlayer`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[
       star,
       star points=8,
       star point height=1.2mm,
       ball color=violet,
       draw=blue!50,
       font=\bf
    ] at (current page.center) {I'M FROM VIETNAMESE};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```