# A Tunisian flag on Tikz using a macro "m-grams"

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I tried to represent the flag of my country.
I typed this code. But I believe that the position of stars, circles, ... is not so respected. In addition I have a left margin "white band" I want to eliminate it, but without result.

Please can you help me get the correct code.

```
%A tunisian flag
%Author: Fethi GHARIANI
%using Tom Bombadil code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58903/how-to-draw-star-in-tikz-background who uses a macro for drawing stars as well as "n-grams"
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[norsk,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false,paperwidth=24cm,paperheight=16cm,margin=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}




% inner radius, outer radius, tips, rot angle, options étoile
\newcommand{\tstar}[5]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\starangle}{360/#3}
\draw[#5] (#4:#1)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#3}
{ -- (#4+\x*\starangle-\starangle/2:#2) -- (#4+\x*\starangle:#1)
}
-- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\ngram}[4]{% outer radius, tips, rot angle, options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\starangle}{360/#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\innerradius}{#1*sin(90-\starangle)/sin(90+\starangle/2)}
\tstar{\innerradius}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\definecolor{rec}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{cir}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{hon}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{sta}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[rec] rectangle (24cm,16cm);
  \fill[cir] (12,8) circle (4cm);
  \fill[hon] (12,8) circle (3cm);
  \fill[sta] (12.8,8) circle (2.4cm);
  \ngram{1.5}{5}{72}{red,thick,fill=red,xshift=13.2cm,yshift=8cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The stripe one the left can be eliminated via adding a `\noindent` as the first line after `\begin{document}`.  As far as the location of the starts and circles it should just be a matter of tweaking the coordinates to your liking. But comparing to [this flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Tunisia.svg), the positioning and size look pretty good.  I can't see what you positioning needs to be changed.

Comment: @Peter Grill. thank you very much, It works for the margin.

Comment: On the size and position, please see for example, http://dc444.4shared.com/img/px48cTom/s7/Dimension_flagTunisia.png

Comment: With `xshift=12.8cm` (instead of `13.2cm`), the star is located in the center of the inner circle...

Comment: @Paul Gabriot. thank's, because i have a problem with the star position.

Answer (score 13):

No n-grams code is required. Standard `star` node shape can do.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{206,17,38}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Use wikipedia's dimensions
  \fill[red] rectangle (12, 8);
  \fill[white] (6,4) circle (2);
  \fill[red] (6,4) circle (1.5);
  \fill[white] (6.4,4) circle (1.2);
  \node[star,fill=red, minimum size=1.8cm, rotate=90, star point ratio=2.617,inner sep=0pt] at (6.4,4) {};
  % Star point ratio is GoldenRatio^2 (1.618^2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Dimensions were taken from [the reglamentary specification after 1999 law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mesures_drapeau_Tunisie_apres_1999.svg). This specification says nothing about the star shape and rotation, but it is safe to assume that it is a regular pentagram and that the flag has a horizontal symmetry axe, which completes the required information.

## Update

There is the [pre-1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mesures_drapeau_Tunisie_avant_1999.svg) version:

[image: pre1999]

In this case I wrote a code more complex, in order to show a different technique. All elements in the flag are tikz nodes, and the styles define their size and position. Also all dimensions are relative to `\flagwidth` which can be changed at will.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\definecolor{red}{RGB}{206,17,38}
\def\flagwidth{6cm}
\tikzset{
flag/.style = { 
  fill=red, 
  minimum width=\flagwidth, 
  minimum height=2/3*\flagwidth, 
  inner sep = 0pt,
},
inner circle/.style = {
  fill = white,
  minimum size=1/3*\flagwidth, 
  circle,
  inner sep = 0pt,
},
crescent/.style = {
  fill = red,
  minimum size = 2/9*\flagwidth,
  circle,
  inner sep = 0pt,
  after node path = {node[moon] {}},
},
moon/.style = {
  fill = white,
  xshift= 1/45*\flagwidth,
  minimum size = 1/5*\flagwidth,
  inner sep = 0pt, 
  circle,
 },
inner star/.style = {
  fill = red,
  star, 
  inner sep = 0pt,
  xshift= 1/30*\flagwidth,
  minimum size=4/27*\flagwidth,
  rotate=90, 
  star point ratio=2.617,
}
}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.01]
% Use pre 1999 dimensions
% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mesures_drapeau_Tunisie_avant_1999.svg
\draw node[flag] {} 
      node[inner circle]  {} 
      node[crescent] {}
      node[inner star] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought of this question. "How to change this code."

Comment: @FethiG. You are right, I didn't answer directly your question, sorry. But I thought you could be interested in a simpler a more compact solution. And, anyway, I "changed your code" didn't I? :-)

Comment: not at all, I think to ask how to change this code, because, I believe that is very long. The reglamentary specification after 1999 law, changes the position of the 3rd circle, but I don't like it. Thank's.

Comment: Really, I thank you very much. I'm a biginner in Latex and Tikz, but I understand.

Comment: The red color should be {206,17,38} (RGB) (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drapeau_de_la_Tunisie#Description).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thank you! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Turkish Flag:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{227, 10, 23}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
% Use wikipedia's dimensions
  \fill[red] rectangle (12, 8);%G=8, L=12, L=1.5 G
   \fill[white] (4,4) circle (2);
   \fill[red] (4.5,4) circle (1.6);
    \node[star,fill=white, minimum size=2cm, rotate=90, star point ratio=2.617,inner sep=0pt] at (6.83333333333,4) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Tunisian and the Turkish flag according to their construction sheets created with `l3draw` (note that the halfmoons are constructed not simply by patching two circles over each other, but by calculating the angle and the coordinates for drawing two arcs):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, multi=draw]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \myflags_draw_five_pointed_star:nnn #1 #2 #3 {
    \draw_scope_begin:
        \draw_transform_shift:n { #1 }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
        \int_step_inline:nnnn { 72 } { 72 } { 360 } {
            \draw_path_lineto:n 
                { \draw_point_polar:nn { 2 / ( 3 + sqrt(5) ) * #2 } { #3 + ##1 - 36 } }
            \int_compare:nNnF { ##1 } = { 360 } {
                \draw_path_lineto:n { \draw_point_polar:nn { #2 } { #3 + ##1 } }
            }
        }
        \draw_path_close:
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    \draw_scope_end:
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { en }
\tl_new:N \l_myflags__intersect_circles_tl
\fp_new:N \l_myflags_crescent_outer_angle_fp
\fp_new:N \l_myflags_crescent_inner_angle_fp
\cs_new:Npn \myflags_draw_crescent:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_myflags_crescent_intersect_circles_tl { 
        \draw_point_intersect_circles:nnnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { 2 } 
    }
    \fp_set:Nn \l_myflags_crescent_outer_angle_fp {
        atand ( 
            \clist_item:en { \l_myflags_crescent_intersect_circles_tl } { 2 } - 
                \clist_item:en { \draw_point:n { #1 } } { 2 } , 
            \clist_item:en { \l_myflags_crescent_intersect_circles_tl } { 1 } - 
                \clist_item:en { \draw_point:n { #1 } } { 1 }
        ) 
    }
    \fp_set:Nn \l_myflags_crescent_inner_angle_fp {
        atand ( 
            \clist_item:en { \l_myflags_crescent_intersect_circles_tl } { 2 } - 
                \clist_item:en { \draw_point:n { #3 } } { 2 } , 
            \clist_item:en { \l_myflags_crescent_intersect_circles_tl } { 1 } - 
                \clist_item:en { \draw_point:n { #3 } } { 1 }
        ) 
    }
    \draw_path_moveto:n { \l_myflags_crescent_intersect_circles_tl }
    \draw_path_arc:nnn { \l_myflags_crescent_outer_angle_fp } 
        { 360 - \l_myflags_crescent_outer_angle_fp } { #2 }
    \draw_path_arc:nnn { 360 - \l_myflags_crescent_inner_angle_fp } 
        { \l_myflags_crescent_inner_angle_fp } { #4 }
    \draw_path_close:
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{draw}{ }{ 
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \draw_begin:
}{ 
    \draw_end:
    \ExplSyntaxOff
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{draw}

    \color_fill:nn { RGB } { 206 , 17 , 38 }
    \draw_path_rectangle_corners:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 12cm , 8cm }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

    \color_fill:n { white }
    \draw_path_circle:nn { 6cm , 4cm } { 2cm }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

    \color_fill:nn { RGB } { 206 , 17 , 38 }
    \myflags_draw_crescent:nnnn { 6cm , 4cm } { 1.5cm } { 6.4cm , 4cm } { 1.2cm } 
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    
    \color_fill:nn { RGB } { 206 , 17 , 38 }
    \myflags_draw_five_pointed_star:nnn { 6.4cm , 4cm } { 0.9cm } { 180 }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

\end{draw}

\begin{draw}

    \color_fill:nn { RGB } { 227 , 10 , 23 }
    \draw_path_rectangle_corners:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 12cm , 8cm }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

    \color_fill:n { white }
    \myflags_draw_crescent:nnnn { 4cm , 4cm } { 2cm } { 4.5cm , 4cm } { 1.6cm } 
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    
    \myflags_draw_five_pointed_star:nnn { 6.4cm , 4cm } { 1cm } { 180 }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

\end{draw}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Amazing. Never used l3draw myself but the result looks very good

Comment: Note that extracting *x* and *y* parts of point coordinates should probably not be done via `\clist_item:en`, but I know of no  better solution to extract items from tuples.