# TikZ: add "alt tag/caption/invisible text" for accessibility

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf, accessibility

I'm using this [amazing tex.sx answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11395/33752) tikz star macro for rendering a x-out-of-y stars graphic for my skills on my resumé.

The resume is done with xelatex and exported to pdf. 
Because it is a resumé, I'm concerned about it being machine readable.

Is there any way to add some alt tag/caption/label/invisible text to the output of the tikz, so it can be obtained when doing copy paste of the pdf?

Also, related question: Is there something like blind friendly latex?

I tried \pdftooltip from the \pdfcomment package, but didn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add an invisible node on top of the stars that contains the score. That way, the text won't be visible, but it will be copy/pastable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand\score[2]{
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfxa{#1+1}
\tikzset{
    scorestars/.style={
        star,
        star points=5,
        star point ratio=2.25,
        draw,
        inner sep=1.3pt,
        anchor=outer point 3
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \pgfmathparse{(\i<=#1?"yellow":"gray")}
    \edef\starcolor{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (\i*1.75ex,0) node[name=star\i,scorestars,fill=\starcolor]  {};
  }
  \node [font=\tiny, opacity=0] at (current bounding box.mid) {#1/#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\score{0}{5} A meagre result.

\score{4}{5} Much better

\score{5}{5} Perfect score!

\end{document}
```

Comment: that was fast!
perfect solution for tikzs.
If you don't mind, I will ask @Jake to add this to his [tikz star macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11395/33752).
Many thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [accsupp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) package.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand\score[2]{%
\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={#1 of #2}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfxa{#1+1}%
\tikzstyle{scorestars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25, draw,inner sep=1.3pt,anchor=outer point 3]%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \pgfmathparse{(\i<=#1?"yellow":"gray")}
    \edef\starcolor{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (\i*1.75ex,0) node[name=star\i,scorestars,fill=\starcolor]  {};
   }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}
\score{0}{5} A meagre result.

\score{4}{5} Much better

\score{5}{5} Perfect score!

\end{document}
```

Selection output:

```
0 of 5 A meagre result.
4 of 5 Much better
5 of 5 Perfect score!
```

Note: I'd have to escape line ends in the `\score` macro to avoid unintentional spaces.