# Get partly filled circle symbol scale linearly with parameter

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a `\rating` command that draws a partly filled circle, according to a numeric parameter between 0 and 100:

[image: sequence of 10 circular rating symbols]

**Question:** How can I modify the expression for determining the angles in `arc`, so that the filling rises more steadily over the whole value range? Right now, ratings from 0 to 20 look empty, 80 to 100 look completely filled and only in between there is a steady rise.

**Clarification:** Rather than a mathematically rigoros expression, I am looking for the simplest expression that *looks right*, i.e. that `\rating{25}`, `\rating{50}` and `\rating{75}` visually look like 1/4, 2/4 and 3/4.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rating}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[lightgray] ({270-1.8*#1}:1ex) arc ({270-1.8*#1}:{270+1.8*#1}:1ex) -- cycle;
\draw[black, thin, radius=1ex] (0,0) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
This really should scale\dots
\rating{0} \rating{10} \rating{20} \rating{30} \rating{40} \rating{50}
\rating{50} \rating{60} \rating{70} \rating{80} \rating{90} \rating{100}
\dots linearly.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a maths question rather than a TeX one.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108622/19356

Comment: @Jubobs: Partly agreed: I'm more interested in a working (in the TeX environment) solution than a mathematically correct one.

Comment: @ojdo If a simple mathematical solution exists, why not use it?

Comment: @Jubobs: I accepteded the clip answer because it would work even for other shapes without the need for `asin` etc. Frankly, I am overwhelmed by the number of options I was offered. I will probably adapt the optional parameter idea of your answer.

Comment: @ojdo True: my solution only applies to a circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an aside, please see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Here is a solution using a `clip`ped path in TikZ. Note that the clip path cannot have extra options added, so I've drawn the circle with your specifications separately, outside the scope of the `\clip` path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rating}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,1) circle (1);
      \fill[lightgray] (-1,0) rectangle (1,#1/50);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[black, thin, radius=1] (0,1) circle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
This really should scale\dots
\foreach \h in {0,5,...,100} {\rating{\h}}
\dots linearly.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aside noted, elegance of the clip path solution appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5):

All you need is a different parameterisation of the angle; see below for details.

[image]

Additionally,

1. since you seem to use `\rating` "inline", you may want to simply use `\tikz` instead of a `tikzpicture` environment;
2. avoid spurious spaces in the definition of `\rating` (instead, insert a space between calls to `\rating`, wherever one is needed);
3. instead of hardcoding `1ex` as the radius, make it an optional argument, for more flexibility;
4. as already pointed out by Paul in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194960/21891), avoid the `minimal` class when using `tikz`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rating}[2][1ex]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\th{asin(#2/50-1)}% (theta angle of polar coordinates)
    \tikz{%
      \fill[lightgray] (\th:#1) arc (\th:-180-\th:#1) -- cycle;
      \draw[black, thin, radius=#1] (0,0) circle;
    }%
}

\begin{document}
This really should scale\dots
\foreach \h in {0,10,...,100} {\rating{\h} }
\dots linearly.

\section*{Parameterisation explained}

Let~\(R\) be the disk radius. In polar coordinates,
%
\[
  y = R \sin \theta \,.
\]
%
Therefore,
%
\[
  \theta = \arcsin \frac{y}{R}  \,.
\]
%
Because the quantity~\(y/R\) varies over~\([-1,1]\)
but you want a parameter~\(u\) that varies over~\([0,100]\),
the right affine transformation will get you there:
%
\[
  \frac{y}{R} = \frac{u}{50} - 1 \,.
\]
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way with `TikZ` but without explicit clipping:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{circle mark/.pic={
  \draw [path picture={%
    \fill (path picture bounding box.south west) |-  
      ($(path picture bounding box.south east)!#1/100!(path picture bounding box.north east)$) 
      |- cycle;}] circle [radius=1ex];
}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,10,...,100}
  \tikz\path pic{circle mark=\i};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this also be done clockwise. Eg 25% is black from 12 o clock until 3 o clock etc?

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}


\newcommand\rating[2][.25pt]{%
\psset{unit=#1,runit=#1}
\pspicture(100,100)
\psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,linewidth=0](50,50){50}}
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray](100,#2)
\endpsclip
\pscircle[dimen=m](50,50){50}
\endpspicture}

\begin{document}
Linearly filled circles:\\
\foreach \i in {0,10,...,100}{\rating{\i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\rateColor{black!40}
\newcommand\rating[2][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else\gdef\rateColor{#1}\fi
  \psset{unit=1ex}%
  \pspicture[dimen=inner](-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)
    \psclip{\pscircle{1}}
      \psframe*[linecolor=\rateColor](-1,-1)(!1 #2 100 div 2 mul 1 sub)
    \endpsclip\pscircle{1}
  \endpspicture}

\begin{document}
This really should scale \dots

\tiny
\multido{\iA=0+10}{21}{\ifnum\iA>100\expandafter\rating\expandafter{\the\numexpr200-\iA}\else\rating{\iA}\fi} \par
\normalsize
\rating[red]{0} 
\multido{\iA=10+10}{20}{\ifnum\iA>100\expandafter\rating\expandafter{\the\numexpr200-\iA}\else\rating{\iA}\fi} \par
\Large
\rating[blue]{0} 
\multido{\iA=10+10}{20}{\ifnum\iA>100\expandafter\rating\expandafter{\the\numexpr200-\iA}\else\rating{\iA}\fi} \par
\end{document}
```

[image]