# How to add 25/50/75/100% filled circles to a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, booktabs, circles

Often I see in a paper a table with a column of circles which are filled for 25/50/75/100% to show priority/level of meeting requirements, to mention yes/no/unknown/NA etc?

- Do such (usage of) circles have a specific name?

  - How can I add such circles to a table in an easy way?
  - What are common other (visualization) techniques used in scientific papers to visualize this kind of levels/ranking/categorization? So far I have seen these circles and ++ .. --. But I am novice so maybe there are more techniques.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an image of such circles to your question? I'm not sure I understand which ones you're referring to.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194955/get-partly-filled-circle-symbol-scale-linearly-with-parameter and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/drawing-stars-similar-with-tikz/108622#108622

Comment: Paul. This link is awesome but can we do this rating also clockwise eg 25% is black fill 12-3 o clock

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean something like below? Make sure to define your own commands. Like this, you can still switch to something different later on

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-Math}
\newcommand*{\noPrior}{\ensuremath{\mdlgwhtcircle}}
\newcommand*{\quarterPrior}{\ensuremath{\circleurquadblack}}
\newcommand*{\halfPrior}{\ensuremath{\circlerighthalfblack}}
\newcommand*{\threeQuarterPrior}{\ensuremath{\blackcircleulquadwhite}}
\newcommand*{\fullPrior}{\ensuremath{\mdlgblkcircle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    Symbol & Meaning\\
    \midrule
    \noPrior & \SI{0}{\percent}\\
    \quarterPrior & \SI{25}{\percent}\\
    \halfPrior & \SI{50}{\percent}\\
    \threeQuarterPrior & \SI{75}{\percent}\\
    \fullPrior & \SI{100}{\percent}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is an idea for Ti*k*Z:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\priority}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.15]%
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \fill[fill opacity=0.5,fill=blue] (0,0) -- (90:{#1>0?1:0}) arc (90:90-#1*3.6:1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    Symbol & Meaning\\
    \midrule
    \priority{0} & \SI{0}{\percent}\\
    \priority{15} & \SI{15}{\percent}\\
    \priority{33} & \SI{33}{\percent}\\
    \priority{75} & \SI{75}{\percent}\\
    \priority{100} & \SI{100}{\percent}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes cool however not usable for plain pdflatex. Also is there a TIKZ impl which works from 0% to 100%?

Comment: @robert Pls see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

For 0%, 50%, and 100% you could use the `fontawesome` glyphs `\faCircleO`, `\faAdjust`, and `\faCircle`.  Requires `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faCircle
\faAdjust
\faCircleO
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you :) Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A variation of LaRiFaRi's nice answer using the `l3draw` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \FilledCircle } { m } {
    \draw_begin:
        \draw_baseline:n { -.1em }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { 0em , 0.75em }
        \draw_path_arc:nnn { 90 } { 90 - #1 * 360 } { 0.5em }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { 0em , 0.25em }
        \draw_path_close:
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \draw_path_circle:nn { 0em , 0.25em } { 0.5em }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    \draw_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    Symbol & Meaning \\
    \midrule
    \FilledCircle{0} & \SI{0}{\percent} \\
    \FilledCircle{.33} & \SI{33}{\percent} \\
    \FilledCircle{.25} & \SI{25}{\percent} \\
    \FilledCircle{.5} & \SI{50}{\percent} \\
    \FilledCircle{.75} & \SI{75}{\percent} \\
    \FilledCircle{1} & \SI{100}{\percent} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]