# Add the following skill format to the moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to format my IT skills as in the image format underneath but I do not have any ideahow can I manage that. I tried it with `\cventry` but it does not look as in the image. I appreciate your help.

**Latex code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\let\makeletterfoot\makecvfoot
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\firstname{Alex}
\familyname{Testmann}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Bahnhof Straße 11}{12345 Berlin}
\mobile{0456/ 345 45 345 }
\email{alex.testmann.com}
\photo[3.5cm]{testsbild}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Kenntnisse}

\end{document}
```

**image[image]**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in the example file of `moderncv` you can see several commands helping you to create your wished content.

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\let\makeletterfoot\makecvfoot
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{5cm} 
\setlength{\footskip}{39pt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\firstname{Alex}
\familyname{Testmann}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Bahnhof Straße 11}{12345 Berlin}
\mobile{0456/ 345 45 345 }
\email{alex.testmann.com}
\photo[3.5cm]{example-image}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Kenntnisse}
\cvitem{Programmierung}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Java}{+++}{Gute Kenntnisse}
\cvitemwithcomment{PHP}{++}{Erweiterte Grundkenntisse}
\cvitemwithcomment{GIT}{+}{Grundkenntnisse}

\cvitem{Betriebssysteme}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Java}{+++}{PHP}{++}
\cvdoubleitem{GIT}{+}{}{}
\cvitem{Definitionen}{+ Grundkenntnisse, ++ Erweiterte Grundkenntnisse, }

\cvitem{Programmierung}{}
\cvitem{}{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}l}
  Java & +++ \\
  PHP  & ++  \\
  GIT  & +   \\
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

giving the following result:

[image: result of the mwe above]

Now you can choose the variant you want to use ...

Comment: Do you know of more appealing UTF-8 signs like stars? For TikZ-based approaches there is [TeX.SE: Drawing stars similiar with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/drawing-stars-similar-with-tikz) and [TeX.SE: How to create dotted counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301012/how-to-create-dotted-counter)