# LaTeX command for half unfilled \bigstar

Tags: symbols

The symbol `\bigstar` produces a black star. I find commands that they produce a half star but I don't find command that make a half filled star like this:

[image]

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Hi and welcome, I do not know if there's a symbol, but look here, maybe you can use tikz to create what you need https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11395/90297

Comment: For the future there is a list of available symbols here: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf

Answer (score 3):

`fontawesome` got you coverd:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faStarHalfO
\end{document}
```

[image]