# To draw a chessboard

Tags: tables, chess

How to draw a chessboard with unconventional house's colors?

I can draw alternately black and white house. But,  I can't draw alternating column colors black and white.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. If you have some code producing a chessboard, and you only want to change the colours, it would be nice if you added that code in a minimal example (with documentclass and any necessary packages) to your question. You've gotten a couple of answers already, but in general it is always nice if you add such examples. Makes it easier for those trying to help.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the [chessboard](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
\newgame
\chessboard
\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can personalize your chessboard as you want. For example (if I understand correctly what you want to achieve):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC3}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
\newgame
\chessboard[
    coloremph,
    fieldmaskcolor=red,
    fieldcolor=red,
    emphareas={a1-a8,c1-c8,e1-e8,g1-g8},
    coloremph,
    fieldmaskcolor=white,
    fieldcolor=white,
    emphareas={b1-b8,d1-d8,f1-f8,h1-h8}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or more strange configurations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC3}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
\newgame
\chessboard[
    coloremph,
    fieldmaskcolor=red,
    fieldcolor=red,
    emphareas={a8-b7,c3-c5,e4-e7,f7-g7,g1-h3},
    coloremph,
    fieldmaskcolor=white,
    fieldcolor=white,
    emphareas={a1-b6,c6-d8,c1-d2,d3-d5,e8-h8,e1-f3,f4-h6}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think link is rot new one is this one http://repo.iut.ac.ir/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf

Comment: I would recommend to use the link from ctan [https://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard?lang=en](https://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard?lang=en)

Answer (score 19):

### With PSTricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\psset{linecolor=brown}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(8,8)
    \multips(0,0)(0,2){4}{%
        \multips(0,0)(2,0){4}{%
            \psframe*(1,1)\psframe*(1,1)(2,2)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Algorithm**

The following animation shows the algorithm used to generate the board.

[image]

### Without PSTricks

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
\foreach \y in {0,2,...,6}{
    \foreach \x in {0,2,...,6}{
        \fill (\x,\y) rectangle (1+\x,1+\y) rectangle (2+\x,2+\y);}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As the output is visually identical, I think I don't need to re-show it again.

Comment: Can I to change black color to brown color?

Comment: @benedito from @kiss 's code: `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[brown]
\foreach \x in {0,2,...,6}
\foreach \y in {0,2,...,6}
\fill (\x,\y) rectangle (1+\x,1+\y) rectangle (2+\x,2+\y);
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 18):

Since the question contains the text "house's color unconventional", I assumed you need control over the colors to be applied and over the size and number of rows/columns of the chessboard. The following allows you to do that; you can easily draw a conventional chessboard, but you can also easily produce unconventional patterns as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{keyval}

\def\Side{\ChessSide}
\newcommand\ChessBoxA{%
  {\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\color{\ChessColori}\rule{\Side}{\Side}}}}
\newcommand\ChessBoxB{%
  {\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\color{\ChessColorii}\rule{\Side}{\Side}}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Row[1]{%
  \par\nobreak\nointerlineskip\vskip-\fboxrule%
  \@tfor\@tempa:=#1 \do {\csname ChessBox\@tempa\endcsname\kern-\fboxrule}}
\define@key{chessB}{side}{\def\ChessSide{#1}}
\define@key{chessB}{colori}{\def\ChessColori{#1}}
\define@key{chessB}{colorii}{\def\ChessColorii{#1}}
\setkeys{chessB}{
  side=1.5em,
  colori=black!70,
  colorii=white}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Conventional[1][]{%
\begin{Chessboard}[#1]
\Row{B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A}
\Row{A,B,A,B,A,B,A.B}
\Row{B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A}
\Row{A,B,A,B,A,B,A.B}
\Row{B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A}
\Row{A,B,A,B,A,B,A.B}
\Row{B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A}
\Row{A,B,A,B,A,B,A.B}
\end{Chessboard}%
}

\newenvironment{Chessboard}[1][]
  {\setkeys{chessB}{#1}%
  \par\medskip\setlength\parindent{0pt}}
  {\par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\Conventional

\Conventional[side=10pt,colori=Bittersweet]

\begin{Chessboard}
\Row{B,A,B,A,A,B}
\Row{A,A,B,A,B,B}
\Row{B,A,B,A,B,B}
\Row{A,A,B,B,A,B}
\Row{B,A,B,A,B,B}
\Row{A,A,A,A,B,A}
\end{Chessboard}

\begin{Chessboard}[side=0.8em,colori=MidnightBlue,colorii=Dandelion]
\Row{A,A,B,B}
\Row{A,A,B,B}
\Row{B,B,A,A}
\Row{B,B,A,A}
\end{Chessboard}

\begin{Chessboard}[side=1.2cm,colori=Maroon,colorii=ForestGreen]
\Row{A,A,B,B,A}
\Row{A,B,B,B,A}
\Row{A,B,B,A,A}
\Row{B,B,A,A,B}
\Row{B,B,B,A,B}
\end{Chessboard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the example, a simple key=value mechanism allows to control the side of each square, as well as the two colors used to produce the pattern. The keys are `side` (default=`1.5em`), `colori` (default=`black!70`), and `colorii` (default=`white`).

`\Conventional` draws a conventional chessboard; using an optional argument you can pass the options to this conventional chessboard.

The Chessboard environment allows you to have different patterns; inside this environment you use the `\Row` command to specify each row; the mandatory argument is a comma separated list of characters "A" and "B" which correspond to the colors to be used in that row; for example, with the default settings,

```
\begin{Chessboard}
\Row{B,A,B,A,A,B}
\end{Chessboard}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: mmm maybe you understand better than me the question :-)

Comment: Thanks. One question: How a draw a chessboard with color alternately black and white square 2 by 2?

Comment: @benedito Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @benedito also, please consider editing the title of your question so that it is clear that you are looking for unconventional cheesboard-like designs.

Comment: Unconventional Cheessboard (8 by 8) - I would also like to see how to make a board with only two white houses, no neighbours, and black color on  the rest.

Comment: Unconventional Chessboard - - Gonzalo,When I compilie your update, does not appear any figure

Comment: @benedito please see my newly updated answer.

Comment: Gonzalo,Thanks very much. That's what I wanted. Very good. SHOW!

Comment: Unconventional Chessboard - Gonzalo,I want to separate the figures in separate files.
What commands should I erase by time?

Comment: @benedito this is a new requirement; in this place, we try to keep one question per post. Please, feel free to open a follow-up question explaining your new requirement (and perhaps linking to this question to provide background). Also, since you have received some nice answers, please consider accepting the one that you consider best solved your problem.

Comment: 8 by 8 Board with subboards 2 by 2 alternately painted white and black.                                \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC3}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}
\newgame
\chessboard[
    coloremph,
    fieldmaskcolor=black,
    fieldcolor=black,
    emphareas={a8-b7,e8-f7,c6-d5,g6-h5, a4-b3,e4-f3,c2-d1, g2-h1},
    coloremph,
    fieldmaskcolor=white,
    fieldcolor=white,
    emphareas={c8-d7,g8-h7,a6-b5,e6-f5,c4-d3,g4-h3,a2-b1,e2-f1}]
\end{document}

Comment: When I use this in Beamer, I get spaces between the rows. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

A simplistic [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) approach using [Using \pgfmathparse and \ifnum for a TikZ checkerboard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/using-pgfmathparse-and-ifnum-for-a-tikz-checkerboard)

[image: chessboard picture]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7} \foreach \y in {0,...,7}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "white" : "black"}
        \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
        \path[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    }
    \draw (0,0)--(0,8)--(8,8)--(8,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The last `draw` should be ended by `cycle` to make the bottom left corner properly fused.

Comment: to the downvoter, please always leave a comment- it will help me improve the answer

Comment: @cmhughes the lower left square should be dark, might explain the downvote.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the conventional coloring.

Answer (score 3):

If you draw all square edges with a single loop, you can just instruct to color the chessboard: the squares to be colored will be selected automatically.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=6mm,y=6mm]
\draw[fill=black!30,even odd rule] (0,0) 
foreach \n in {1,2,3,4} { -- ++ (8,0) -- ++ (0,1) -- ++ (-8,0) -- ++ (0,1) } -- (8,8)
foreach \n in {1,2,3,4} { -- ++ (0,-8) -- ++ (-1,0) -- ++ (0,8) -- ++ (-1,0) } -- cycle
foreach[count=\n] \m in {A,B,...,H} { (-0.4,\n-0.5) node {\n} (\n-0.5,-0.5) node {\m} };
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

Comment: could make this fully compilable, please? everyone else, who answered, did as well. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=6mm,y=6mm]
    \draw[fill=black!30,even odd rule] (0,0) 
    foreach \n in {1,2,3,4} { -- ++ (8,0) -- ++ (0,1) -- ++ (-8,0) -- ++ (0,1) } -- (8,8)

    foreach \n in {1,2,3,4} { -- ++ (0,-8) -- ++ (-1,0) -- ++ (0,8) -- ++ (-1,0) } -- cycle

    foreach[count=\n] \m in {a,b,...,h} { (-0.4,\n-0.5) node {\n} (\n-0.5,-0.5) node {\m} };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[shift={+(1,1)}] (0,0) -- (0,8) -- (8,8) -- (8,0) -- cycle;
\foreach \x in {2,4,6,8}
\foreach \y in {2,4,6,8}
\draw[fill=black] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
\foreach \x in {1,3,5,7}
\foreach \y in {1,3,5,7}
\draw[fill=black] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Making even minor changes to the above will get you unconventional stuff. By switching the second fill to green:

[image]

On top of the previous change, by changing the first {2,4,6,8} to {1,3,5,7}:

[image]

And on top of the previous two changes, by changing the final {1,3,5,7} to {1,2,3,4}:

[image]

It's pretty easy to customize.