# Tree of matrices and grids

Tags: trees, tikz-matrix, grids

I can make a grid and set queens on it with a matrix. But now I want to make them a node, because I want it to be part of tree. And now the grid and the matrix are separated.
Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
 
 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & \symqueen \\
\symqueen &   &   &   \\
  &   & \symqueen &  \\};
\end{tikzpicture} 



\begin{tikzpicture}

\node {

\tikz\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\tikz\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & \symqueen \\
\symqueen &   &   &   \\
  &   & \symqueen &  \\};

};

\end{tikzpicture} 
 
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I have the second one looks like the first ?

Comment: @MS-SPO I would love to know how to place the queens symbol for a given child, because it is exactly what I am struggling to do !

Comment: Did you have a look at the minimal introduction and the PGF manual here: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en ?

Comment: @MS-SPO I did look at the minimal introduction, I might be wrong but there is nothing related to tree in, and my problem is I have no idea how to place the queens in the tree.

Comment: Right, that's what the huge manual is for. Don't be afraid, just navigate to e.g. ch 6 "tutorial", ch. 17 "nodes and edges", ch 20.4 "anchoring a matrix", ch. 21 "making trees grow" etc. Prefer scanning over strict reading, at least in your first pass ;-)

Comment: May be this is where you want to end up with? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133332/to-draw-a-chessboard/133383#133383 . You can also downsize the chessboard with this package, e.g. to 4x4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, even other approaches are possible. For example using only matrix and anchors you can get:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\Row}[4]{#1 \& #2 \& #3 \& #4 \\}
\newcommand{\vvRow}{\Row{}{}{}{}\Row{}{}{}{}}%two void rows
\newcommand{\vvvRow}{\Row{}{}{}{}\Row{}{}{}{}\Row{}{}{}{}}%three void rows

\newcommand{\myGrid}[3]{\begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
ampersand replacement=\&,
inner sep=0.5pt,
nodes={
    inner sep=0pt,
    text width=.5cm,
    align=center,
    text height=0.4cm,
    text depth=.1cm},
nodes in empty cells]
(#2){#3};
\foreach \hvL in {1,...,3}
\draw[gray] (#2-1-\hvL.north east) -- (#2-4-\hvL.south east)
            (#2-\hvL-1.south west) -- (#2-\hvL-4.south east);
\draw[gray] (#2-4-1.south west) rectangle (#2-1-4.north east);
\end{scope}
}%\myGrid{position}{name}{contents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\sq{\symqueen}
\def\rw{0.5}
%first grid row
\myGrid{(0,0)}{g-1-1}{\Row{\sq}{}{}{}\vvvRow}
%second grid row
\myGrid{([shift={(-9.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-1-1.south)}{g-2-1}{\Row{\sq}{}{}{}\vvvRow}

\myGrid{([shift={(-3.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-1-1.south)}{g-2-2}{\Row{}{\sq}{}{}\vvvRow}
 
\myGrid{([shift={(3.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-1-1.south)}{g-2-3}{\Row{}{}{\sq}{}\vvvRow}

\myGrid{([shift={(9.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-1-1.south)}{g-2-4}{\Row{}{}{}{\sq}\vvvRow}
%third grid row 
\myGrid{([shift={(-9.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-2-2.south)}{g-3-1}{\Row{}{\sq}{}{}\Row{\sq}{}{}{}\vvRow}
\myGrid{([shift={(-3.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-2-2.south)}{g-3-2}{\Row{}{\sq}{}{}\Row{}{\sq}{}{}\vvRow}
\myGrid{([shift={(3.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-2-2.south)}{g-3-3}{\Row{}{\sq}{}{}\Row{}{}{\sq}{}\vvRow}
\myGrid{([shift={(9.5*\rw,-3*\rw)}]g-2-2.south)}{g-3-4}{\Row{}{\sq}{}{}\Row{}{}{}{\sq}\vvRow}

\foreach \rs/\re/\gs in {1/2/1,2/3/2}
\foreach \gn in {1,...,4}
\draw (g-\rs-\gs.south)  -- (g-\re-\gn.north);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: grid whit queens]

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a way to do this : using tikzpictures inside of tikzpictures.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
 
 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every matrix/.append style={ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of nodes},
    level distance = 3cm,
    level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 3cm},
    level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 2.5cm},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)},
]
\node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
\symqueen \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
    child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \& \symqueen \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
        child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \& \symqueen \&   \&   \\
\symqueen  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
        child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \& \symqueen \&   \&   \\
  \& \symqueen \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
        child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \& \symqueen \&   \&   \\
  \&   \& \symqueen \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
        child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \& \symqueen \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \& \symqueen \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}  
    }
    child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \&   \& \symqueen \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
    child {node {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix, nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}, nodes in empty cells]{
  \&   \&   \& \symqueen \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&   \\
  \&   \&   \&  \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}};
\end{tikzpicture} 

 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulations: you made it :)

Comment: Embedding `tikzpicture` environments is not recommended.